# Descartes and natural inclinations and aversions

Tags: descartes, dualism

Descartes mentions “secondary properties” (qualitative properties) which guide human behavior.

E. g. we can not only recognize that food became spoiled by its odor but we’re immediately repelled by it.

Descartes also admits that these natural inclinations / aversions may become disordered:

> Sick people, for example, may want food or drink that is bad for them. ‘They go wrong because they are ill’ – true, but the difficulty remains. A sick man is one of God’s creatures just as a healthy one is, and in each case it seems a contradiction to suppose that God has given him a nature that deceives him. A badly made clock conforms to the laws of its nature in telling the wrong time, just as a well made and accurate clock does; and we might look at the human body in the same way. We could see it as a kind of machine made up of bones, nerves, muscles, veins, blood and skin in such a way that, even if there were no mind in it, it would still move exactly as it now does in all the cases where movement isn’t under the control of the will or, therefore, of the mind. If such a body suffers from dropsy, for example, and is affected by the dryness of the throat that normally produces in the mind a sensation of thirst, that will affect the nerves and other bodily parts in such a way as to dispose the body to take a drink, which will make the disease worse. Yet this is as natural as a healthy body’s being stimulated by a similar dryness of the throat to take a drink that is good for it. In a way, we might say, it is not natural. Just as we could say that a clock that works badly is ‘departing from its nature’, we might say that the dropsical body that takes a harmful drink is ‘departing from its nature’, that is, from the pattern of movements that usually occur in human bodies. But that involves using ‘nature’ as a way of comparing one thing with another – a sick man with a healthy one, a badly made clock with an accurate one – whereas I have been using ‘nature’ not to make comparisons but to speak of what can be found in the things themselves; and this usage is legitimate. (VI. Meditation)

Of course we can imagine something going wrong “relatively down the line”, like if the sense organs become disordered. This can be explained just like he suggests in his analogy of the broken clock.

But at some point the qualitative experience must arise. Right at this causal bridge between the physical and the mental, must there not be a correct manner of functioning for the human person, and a wrong one?

Isn’t it the case that a disorder at this point is simply not analyzable in Cartesian philosophy?

Comment: Why do you think the causes are forever unanalyzable? I read the opposite: that since what does wrong is a mechanical problem, then with enough information, it can be analyzed mechanically. Also, I don't see Descartes blaming *all* problems solely on the body, it's just that in this discussion he is talking about problems of the body. I don't know what he has to say about mental disorders, but this quote doesn't suggest that he would rule out problems of the mind that are not physical. As a good Catholic, presumably, he believed in demon possession, for example.

Comment: @DavidGudeman in the realm of purely physical causation the clock analogy works, but the qualitative experience must arise at the end of the causal chain, starting with the external physical stimulus (I rephrased the question). So there’s not only physical-mental causation, but we can imagine “disordered” versions of it. Doesn’t Descartes need to claim that at this point no disorder can ever occur? `As a good Catholic, presumably, he believed in demon possession, for example.` Is “demonic possession” a diagnosis of exclusion for him? Or can it be directly recognized?

Comment: I just don't get your point. He believes that the body can be disordered; he believes that qualitative experiences are conditioned by the body, so he believes that qualitative experiences can be disordered. He clearly doesn't believe that the mind is some sort of homunculus sitting on top of the body with its own experience of the world independent of the impressions given it by the body and the bodies senses, which is the only way I can imagine that your question makes sense. If the body is telling the mind that it needs water, then the mind experiences the need for water.